# Eclipse marketplace not working after installing WAS 8.5 plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-8, eclipse-marketplace, ibm-was

I have Eclipse Kepler running on my computer. After I installed IBM Websphere 8.5 plug-in from  the marketplace and restarted my Kepler, I'm not able to re-open the marketplace.

A progress bar is being displayed that says "Retrieving data from http://marketplace.eclipse.org" for 30 minutes plus.

When I uninstall the plug-in, the marketplace works fine.

Why is this happening? Can anyone help me out in figuring?

Appreciate your help.

PS : there is no issue while accessing the link from a browser.

Thanks,
Madhu.

**UPDATE**
The below error is logged when clicking on "Install new software"

```
exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/kepler/compositeContent.xml.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure initializing default SSL context
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:211)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:333)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:274)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:797)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:209)
    ... 11 more
```

**UPDATE**

I just found out the reason. While creating a WAS 8.5 server in eclipse, there is an option called "security is enabled on this server" which we usually check for a secure mode. This hampers with eclipse's marketplace connection settings and thus preventing it from functioning. The only thing I don't understand is how both of these are related and how to overcome the problem.

Hope someone out there can explain :)

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory?

Comment: @greg : updated my post with the error message that I get while clicking on "Install new software". Apart from that, there is no error being logged when trying to access marketplace

Comment: @madhu_sharan - You should totally answer your own question with your update and mark it as the correct answer, as it is. It should be noted that a restart after unchecking was necessary at least in my case. I did not receive the exception you did. In fact, I would receive no exception at all. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. I spent way too much of my life looking for this prior to finding this post.

Comment: Just a guess - what Java are you using for your Eclipse? Is it by chance Java which comes with WebSphere?

Comment: @Gas : Yes. It defaults to WebSphere's java. Is there any direct solution to this problem?

Comment: Try to download Oracle Java and use it for Eclipse or check if it will work if default workspace JRE will not be pointing to WAS Java

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too.  I was trying to install the WAS v8.5 development tools in a workspace that already has WAS 7.0 server setup.  The same error was observed in the log.  Trying to uncheck the "security is enabled on this server" option did not work for me.  (Eclipse Marketplace would be stuck on lunch.)

So I created a new workspace and Eclipse Marketplace can be launched again.  If I then set up a WAS 7.0 Server in this workspace, the same issue occurs.  Removed WAS 7.0 server definition, restarted Eclipse and Eclipse Marketplace launches successfully again.

So the workaround is just to create a new workspace and use Eclipse Marketplace and also to perform your updates + installs for Eclipse.  Just don't add any WAS server to that new workspace.  In fact, just use that new workspace just to launch Marketplace and do install/update.  Simple as that.